# LUIS limits the number of intents to 20

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to build a bot which talks to a LUIS model. The bot would have 35 scenarios, each corresponding to a LUIS intent. Currently, LUIS supports having maximum 20 intents. 
How can I scale this in my code? I am wondering if it is better to have a LUIS model hierarchy, with the parent model calling on to the specific child model. Or should I maintain a list of keywords in my database and call a specific model based on it. I need help to evaluate the pros and cons of both the approaches. Thanks!

Comment: The limit for intents was recently raised from 80 to 500 check this out at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try to replace as many scenarios as you can using BestMatchDialog (at least, 15).

You would still use LuisDialog as your root dialog.
Here's an example:

```
 [Serializable]
public class GreetingsDialog: BestMatchDialog<bool>
{
    [BestMatch(new string[] { "Hi", "Hi There", "Hello there", "Hey", "Hello",
        "Hey there", "Greetings", "Good morning", "Good afternoon", "Good evening", "Good day" },
       threshold: 0.5, ignoreCase: true, ignoreNonAlphaNumericCharacters: true)]
    public async Task WelcomeGreeting(IDialogContext context, string messageText)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hello there. How can I help you?");
        context.Done(true);
    }

    [BestMatch(new string[] { "bye", "bye bye", "got to go",
        "see you later", "laters", "adios" })]
    public async Task FarewellGreeting(IDialogContext context, string messageText)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Bye. Have a good day.");
        context.Done(true);
    }

    public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string messageText)
    {
        context.Done(false);
    }
}
```

From your LuisDialog you can call it this way

```
 [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message, LuisResult result)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await context.Forward(new GreetingsDialog(), GreetingDialogDone, await message, cts.Token);
    }
```

The code above was borrowed from [Ankitbko's MeBot repo](https://github.com/ankitbko/MeBot).

Comment: Thanks! Also, it seems like the number of intents would be relaxed in the next LUIS release.

Comment: @happydevdays  that's great, but be careful with the pricing :P

Comment: it's up to 40 intents now

Comment: +1 for suggesting `BestMatchDialog`. However, using this library will save you only one intent, greetings or farewell. The 15 you mentioned above are utterances.